# Getting 401 unauthorized : Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token in okta web app

Tags: jhipster, okta

I created a jhipster monolithic application (jhipster version v4.14.2). Also I create a Okta web application with following settings:

- Login redirect URIs -> http://localhost:8080/login
- Initiate login URI -> http://localhost:8080
- Create groups for admin and user, setup the claim in the default authorization server, and assign them to the application and my user

I updated the application.yaml of my jhipster application as follow:

```
security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
    oauth2:
        client:
            access-token-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
            user-authorization-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize
            client-id: ????????
            client-secret: ????????
            client-authentication-scheme: form
            scope: openid profile email
        resource:
            filter-order: 3
            user-info-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
            token-info-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect
            prefer-token-info: false
```

When I start the application and then I try to sign in. I do get the Okta login page, however after adding my credential I always get the following error:

```
Your request cannot be processed
Sorry, an error has occurred.

Status: Unauthorized (Unauthorized)
Message: Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token
```

I followed instruction in jhipster security documention and can't make it work. Any idea why I still get the unauthorized error?

Comment: If I look at the okta authorization server i cannot see the userinfo endpoint. is that normal? I cant find any to make it available.

Comment: Things to check: 1) do you have a default authorization server in your Okta tenant, and 2) do you have any errors in your server logs?

Comment: You should be able to see the userinfo endpoint in your OIDC metadata, which is available at https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: thanks i was looking at authorization server metadata instead openid-configuration metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have nothing to do with jhipster. Make sure your you URL for accessing the access token is right.

What Grant type are you using?

https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/implementing-authentication/

I think the error is here:

access-token-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
            user-authorization-uri: https://dev-779125.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize

Is "user-authorization-uri" jhipster way of of asking for "issuer URL"?